# Running windows server 2012 and windows 8 on VM to do DHCP lab

Tags: windows, dns, windows-server-2012, dhcp

I have windows server 2012 installed on a VM along with windows 8 to do DHCP lab (I am new to networking), but the server cannot assign an IP address to windows 8.

I am using a wireless router.

In the server's powershell, I type *ipconfig /all* to see my IP address and subnet mask and my default gateway,

which is IP address:

> 10.0.2.15    255.255.255.0    10.0.2.2

I went to network to set static IP address the same as above and the preferred DNS server is 10.0.2.15.

Then I create a DHCP range: 10.0.2.100 to 10.0.2.200 and DNS server is and I can see my scope in the DHCP view.

I boot up windows 8 on my VM to see it works.
I go back to server to refresh the address release but nothing happens.

In windows 8 , I command prompt the ipconfig /all

> Ipaddress : 10.0.2.15 (which is server address?) subnet mask: 255.255.255.0 default gateway: 10.0.2.2 DNS server : 192.168.1.1

What am I doing wrong? Is the problem with my DNS configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...It's not quite clear what steps you took to set up your server :(.
Exactly why is your DNS server (192.168.1.1) in a different Network? Are you using a relay Agent?

I will assume you have already installed DHCP server role and feature and 
hence have DHCP manager up and running.

Go through the checklist below.

- did you activate the scope?
- did you specify the domain name server (006) IP and  Router (003) IP?
- did you check the 'Address Lease' column to see if DHCP is leasing any Add?
- did you make sure DHCP guard is not enabled?

Install Network monitor to view DHCP transaction between Client and Server.
You should try runnning `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` on client instead of server.

The site link below might also help.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831538.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since DHCP server is using broadcast method to release IP address, you might run into the situation where you have more than 1 DHCP server in your network. Run the IPCONFIG /ALL again to make sure you got the IP from the right DHCP server.